# Use Android Management API with standart GSuite EMM Provider (Google Mobile Management)

Tags: google-workspace, android-management-api

Our company use GSuite with standart EMM Provider (Google Mobile Management).

There is a way to use Android Management API in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the Android Management API to manage the same devices that are managed by G Suite. The Android Management API is an API called by EMM providers, and in the case of G Suite the EMM provider is G Suite itself.

However you can set up devices using the Android Management API directly and still add your G Suite account on it. It would work as long as you haven't set [advanced mobile management](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1734200) in the G Suite console.